# How to find t interval in calculating volume of parametric equations rotated

Tags: parametric

How to find interval $t$ in calculating volume of parametric equations rotated.
$$x=2(t-\sin t),~y=2(1-\cos t)$$
Find the volume as curves are rotated around $x$-axis.
The interval of $t$ is not given, Is there any way to calculate $t$?

Comment: Indeed, the answer very much depends on the interval of $t$ that should be used. By looking at the graph, my guess is that $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$ is one possible option. Or maybe you can express the answer as a function of the maximum value of $t$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the curve [repeats itself](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3D2%28t-sin+t%29%2Cy%3D2%281-cos+t%29+from+0+to+6pi) at each period $2\pi$ we can take the first period interval for $y(t)$ that is $t\in [0,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 0):

The curve $$x=2(t-\sin t),~y=2(1-\cos t)$$

has  its y-intercepts at $$y=2(1-\cos t)=0$$ which includes $t=0$ and $t=2\pi$

Thus if you are interested in the first region rotated, your limits are $t=0$ and $t=2\pi$